# OpenAPI Maven Plugin generates Incorrect Java Interface Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, openapi

I have RestApi `HTTP GET /api/v1/products/{productId}` endpoint which returns `ResponseEntity<ProductInfoDto>` object with `productId` given as **pathVariable**.

I use **OpenApi version** `6.6.0` to create an api specification for this RestApi.

I created **product-openapi.yaml file** to describe this RestApi.

It is my **product-openapi.yaml file**:

```
openapi: "3.0.3"
info:
  title: "Online_Store API"
  version: "1.0.0"
servers:
  - url: "http://localhost:8083"
tags:
  - name: "Product"
    description: "An API for managing and retrieving product information"
paths:
  /api/v1/products/{productId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - "Product"
      summary: "Enables to get a product by its id"
      operationId: "getProductById"
      parameters:
        - name: "productId"
          description: "the identifier of the product which is returned as the return value"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          schema:
            type: "string"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ProductInfoDto"

components:
  schemas:
    ProductInfoDto:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        id:
          type: "string"
          format: "uuid"
        name:
          type: "string"
        description:
          type: "string"
        price:
          type: "number"
          format: "decimal"
        quantity:
          type: "integer"
          format: "int32"

    ApiResponse:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        data:
          type: "object"
        message:
          type: "string"
        httpStatusCode:
          type: "integer"
        timestamp:
          type: "string"
          format: "date-time"
```

My app is written in **Java 17** with **Spring Boot version 3.1.2**.

I created **RestController** as **ProductsEndpoint class** to describe my RestApi.

It is my **ProductsEndpoint class** which presents my RestApi:

```
package com.zufar.onlinestore.product.endpoint;

import com.zufar.onlinestore.openapi.api.ApiApi;
import com.zufar.onlinestore.product.api.ProductApi;
import com.zufar.onlinestore.product.dto.ProductInfoDto;
import com.zufar.onlinestore.product.dto.ProductListWithPaginationInfoDto;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.UUID;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = ProductsEndpoint.PRODUCTS_URL)
public class ProductsEndpoint implements ApiApi {

    public static final String PRODUCTS_URL = "/api/v1/products";

    private final ProductApi productApi;

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductInfoDto> getProductById(@PathVariable final String productId) {
        log.info("Received the request to get the product with productId - {}.", productId);
        ProductInfoDto product = productApi.getProduct(UUID.fromString(productId));
        log.info("The product with productId: {} was retrieved successfully", productId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(product);
    }
}
```

It is **Apache Maven dependencies** which I added to **pom.xml file**:

```
         .....
          ....
           ...      
    <properties>
       <openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>5.3.0</openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>
        <jackson-databind-nullable.version>0.2.1</jackson-databind-nullable.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.7.0</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
        <javax.annotation-api.version>1.3.2</javax.annotation-api.version>
        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         .....
          ....
           ...
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.annotation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <build>
       <plugins>
         .....
          ....
           ...
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/product-openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.zufar.onlinestore.openapi.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.zufar.onlinestore.product.dto</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <generateModels>false</generateModels>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Well, I execute `mvn clean package` Apache Maven command to build the project. This way OpenApi Maven plugin generate `public interface ApApi` where I use in `public class ProductsEndpoint implements ApiApi`.

**The issue is that OpenApi Maven plugin generate generate `public interface ApApi` instead of  `public interface ProductApi` for my RestApi.**

**How I can fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The issue is that OpenApi Maven plugin generate generate public interface ApApi instead of  `public interface ProductApi` for my RestApi.**
>
> **How I can fix it?**

The solution turned out to be simple.

**Solution:
You just need to change configuration of openapi-generator-maven-plugin in pom.xml file by adding `<useTags>true</useTags>`.**

You can see the updated pom.xml file:

```
.....
.....
 <build>
       <plugins>
         .....
          ....
           ...
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/product-openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.zufar.onlinestore.openapi.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.zufar.onlinestore.product.dto</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <generateModels>false</generateModels>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

After updating pom.xml file you can execute `man clean package` command.

This Apache Maven command generate `interface ProductApi` which you can use in the `ProductsEndpoint class` now.

You can see the updated `ProductsEndpoint class` which which implements `interface ProductApi` instead of `implements ApiApi`:

```
....
..
.
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = ProductsEndpoint.PRODUCTS_URL)
public class ProductsEndpoint implements ProductsApi {
```